# can't run form.html page with tomcat container - 404 HTTP Status?

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

I try to study base of web server programming.
I installed tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 (All works when I type `myIp:8080` I really see correct tomcat page).

And created easy structure:

Under `apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps` => here created `Beer-v1` progect => into this folder `WEB-INF` folder and `form.html`.

Code of `form.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 align=”center”>Beer Selection Page</h1>
        <form method=”POST” 
            action=”SelectBeer.do”>
            Select beer characteristics<p>
            Color:
            <select name=”color” size=”1”>  
                <option value=”light”> light </option>
                <option value=”amber”> amber </option>
                <option value=”brown”> brown </option>
                <option value=”dark”> dark </option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <center>
                <input type=”SUBMIT”>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Into ***WEB-INF*** `web.xml`.

Code of `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
    xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
    xsi:schemaLocation=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd”
    version=”2.4”>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I run `bin/startup.sh` into `apache-tomcat-7.0.42` folder I see next output:

```
root@nazar-desctop:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42# bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

And after type at browser `http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/form.html` - I see:
 **HTTP Status 404 - /Beer-v1/form.html**.

I couldn’t figure out what is wrong.

***Update:***

Content of `catalina.out` - you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/Mv4KSyt6)
And `localhost.2013-09-12.log`:

```
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@d47feb3')
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@27c76b8d')
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:21:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@41fb43a2')
Sep 12, 2013 9:21:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:21:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:30:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:30:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:30:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@30ce9337')
Sep 12, 2013 9:30:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:30:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:44:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:44:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 12, 2013 9:44:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@357c4ab7')
Sep 12, 2013 9:44:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Sep 12, 2013 9:44:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Can you post the content of the Tomcat logs (`catalina.out` and `localhost.<date>.log`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of `catalina.out` caught my eye:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/Beer-v1
Sep 12, 2013 9:17:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 16: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "xmlns".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/Beer-v1/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 16; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "xmlns".
```

Line 1 column 16 of your `web.xml` corresponds to the double quote right after `xmlns=`:

```
 <web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
```

But then I noticed that the double quotes in your `web.xml` don't look like standard double quotes. See the difference between `”` and `"`? So my guess is that Tomcat cannot parse `web.xml` because you're not using the standard double quote but a different character that looks like it but is not interpreted as a delimiter by Tomcat. Try replacing them with standard double quotes.

Comment: I tried fixing this but this repeat again. You [can see here](http://pastebin.com/JrBPcbTd) how I fixed `web.xml`. Do I keep doing smt wrong. I checked accord [this tutorial](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-web-xml.html). I using `"` this kind of quotes. But why it keep falling?

Comment: Make sure that your `web.xml` is using UTF-8 as character encoding. Text editors and IDEs usually have a feature to view/modify the character encoding. Try also adding this line at the beginning of `web.xml`: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: I added but no change. Does exist some way to circumvent this tricky place?

Comment: If you still get the same `SAXParseException` it means that something is wrong in your `web.xml`. Sometimes character encoding problems may result from copy-pasting content from a Web page or another source. Try using a skeleton `web.xml` from a different source.

Comment: Good point! The HTML file is incorrect too but it should be (incorrectly) displayed.

Comment: @DavidLevesque - I am trying the same example from the book and I get `This webpage is not found` error in `chrome`. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque - Can you please help me ? I added a post here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307914/servlet-example-file-not-found Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it by configuring a [context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).
It is discouraged but you can try to add the following in your `conf/server.xml` just to give a try:

```
<Context path="Beer-v1" docBase="webapps/Beer-v1" crossContext="true"
    debug="0" reloadable="false">
</Context>
```

**EDIT**

As David Levesque wrote in his answer, there are some incorrect characters in your web.xml (the `”` issue seems to be fixed there) and your html file. About this point, I am not sure the servlet names with blanks such as `Ch3 Beer` are legal (but once again it shouldn't make a problem form your HTML page).

Please note also that your `servlet-name` values are inconsistent. They should be the same in order to link the class and the url mapping.

I have made a test with your new web.xml file and without modifying the conf/server.xml file and the html file is displayed (with its flaws due to your special `”`). I think as David wrote that there are some remaining invalid characters.

Comment: I tried this. It was some change after running `bin/startup.sh` - all the same and only this line changed `Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`. And after loading to browser I see empty screen.

Comment: @nazar_art from what I have tried on the answer I gave you should work but this is not the good way (btw, sorry but the path I entered was incorrect)

Answer (score -1):

Reason

Tomcat server (or container) 2.2 or above follow a specific standard format for any Web Application Archive.

The HTML and JSP pages must be in the document root directory or more specifically ROOT folder.

The reason here is simple.We are making it easy for client browser to locate the file.
WEB_INF is the folder which contains all the classes.It can also include any kind of file unless you specify correct path in your browser.

Solution
Now coming for the solution which worked for me.

1. I created the same hierarchy you followed.It is beer/WEB_INF and created form.html in it.
2. I placed the entire directory in ROOT folder .
3. I opened the browser, entered `/beerV1/WEB-INF/form.html` and it worked.

Comment: Hi, for the sake of onlooking n00bs... what is it about WEB-INF that means that the server won't look in it? :)

Comment: @PranavSingh - Can you please help me to solve a related problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307914/servlet-example-file-not-found ? Thanks.